# Change web browser shown in the Ubuntu Desktop application launcher?

Tags: browser, default-programs

I'd like to change the web browser shown on the application launcher, from Firefox to Chrome.

This setting obviously differs from the default web browser known to the system because I already set Chrome as the default and it launches links instead of Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locate Chrome In **Applications → Internet**, right click on it and select **Add launcher to panel**.

Comment: Great! Likewise I was able to remove Firefox by right-clicking it on the launcher bar and choosing 'Remove'. Now if only the browser manufactures would code in awareness for the Ubuntu launcher bar/desktop environ to apply the default browser to the launcher automatically, then life would be good.

Comment: And here I've been dragging it to the panel all this time... Which works, just not as elegantly a this.